# Why does the following timed loop, which just counts the number of iterations performed, not always return exactly the same matrix on each trial?

Tags: python, timedelta

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

ntrials = int(input("number of trials? "))
nobs = int(input("number of observations? "))
for t in range(1,ntrials+1):
    print("\ntrial:",t,"\n")
    data = []
    for n in range(nobs):
        obs = []
        for duration in np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]):
            count = 0
            end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=duration)
            while datetime.now() < end_time:
                count += 1
            obs.append(count)
        data.append(obs)
    print(np.array(data))
```

Comment: Because of this `while datetime.now() < end_time`. You can't guarantee stable amount of iterations executed in some time period.

Comment: The computer is doing many things at the same time, so the share of CPU time that your program gets varies.